# ionicキーボードでレイアウトが崩れる

Tags: cordova, ionic2

こんにちは。
現在ionic3.19.1を使ってアプリを作っています。

ユーザーネームを入力してもらう画面を作っているのですが、キーボードが上に上がってきてしまい、レイアウトが崩れてしまいます。
他のアプリもそうなのかと思いLINEで確認したところLINEではキーボードが上に被さり、レイアウトが崩れていませんでした。

ionicでもキーボードを被せられるようにしたいです。どなたかご教授願います。

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

自己解決いたしました。
AndroidManifest.xmlに
`<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">`
を追加したら正常に動作しました。

同じような問題がある方の参考になれば幸いです。